# Javascript recursive function return one single array

Tags: javascript, recursion

My Javascript recursive function is returning multiple arrays, but I just want one single array. I have another file where I call this function, I want one single array that returns the other arrays, but at the moment I am getting a new array per info. I have provided an example of my sample code

```
let childrenStructures = []
export function getInfo(): any {


  let recursiveChildren = (info: any) => {
  let childrenStructure = []
  
    for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      let childrenObj = {}

      childrenObj['info1'] = info[i].info1
      childrenObj['info2'] = info[i].info2
      if (info[i].children) {
        childrenObj['children'] = recursiveChildren(info[i].children)
      }
      childrenStructure.push(childrenObj)
    }
    return childrenStructure
  };

 //start
  for (var i = 0; i < allinfo.length; i++) {
    if (allinfo[i].info) {
          childrenStructures.push(recursiveChildren(allinfo[i].info))
        }
    
      }
  return childrenStructures
}
```

**EXPECTED:**

```
 [
                [ {"info1": 1},{"info2": 2}, {"children": [{"info1": 1},{"info2": 2}]}],
                [ {"info2": 2},{"info2": 3}, {"children":[{"info1": 1},{"info2": 2}]}
 ]
```

**I'm getting:**

```
     [
         [
                    [ {"info1": 1},{"info2": 2}, {"children": [{"info1": 1},{"info2": 2}]}]
         ]
     ]
     [
        [
                    [ {"info2": 2},{"info2": 3}, {"children":[{"info1": 1},{"info2": 2}]}]
         ]
     ]
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
 info: [
    {
      children: [
        {
          info1: 1,
          info2:2
        },
        {
          info1: 1,
          info2: 2
        }
      ],
      info1: 1,
      info2: 2
    },
    {
      children: [
        {
          info1: 1,
          info2:2
        },
        {
          info1: 1,
          info2: 2
        }
      ],
      info1: 1,
      info2: 2
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Can you give the sample input so we can run it?

Comment: Just replace add `childrenStructures = childrenStructures.flat()` before the return?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is much easier than what you're aiming for.  If I understand the requirements properly, this can be accomplished like this:

```js
const transform = (xs) => 
  xs .map (({children, ... rest}) => [
    ... Object .entries (rest) .map (([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})),
    ... (children ? [{children: transform (children)}] : [])
  ])

const info = [{children: [{info1: 1, info2: 2}, {info1: 3, info2: 4}], info1: 5, info2: 6}, {children: [{info1: 7, info2: 8}, {info1: 9, info2: 10}], info1: 11, info2: 12}]

console .log (transform (info))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

For each element in the input, we separate out the `children` node, if any, and for the remainder, we map the result of `Object.entries` into individual objects, and then, if `children` existed, we append an object with the key `"children"` and the value found by recurring on `children`.

Comment: i'm glad you were able to make sense of this one because it was making my eyes hurt! nice work scott ^^